# c# how to propagate a Task exception to the main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, task

I have the code below - I have a thread that runs permanently in the background of a console app. If an exception is thrown within that task I need to to propagate to the main thread. How can I do this?

```
    private void StartTask()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {

                while (_subStatus)
                {
                 // do work here
                 // an exception might be thrown
                }

        });
    }
```

EDIT:
I wasn't clear enough. The task is intended to run for the lifetime of the application. It doesn't need to return a result. I do want to know then there is an exception thrown within the task though. It will look something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       //setup
       StartTask()
       // continue to do other work in the main thread
       while (true)
       {
         // main thread work
       }
    }
```

EDIT2: with the following code I can a least log the error

```
    private async Task StartTask()
    {
       try{
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {

                while (_subStatus)
                {
                 // do work here
                 // an exception might be thrown
                }

        });
        }catch(exception e)
        { //log exception here, still not on the main thread though }
    }
```

Final Edit:
From this answer at the bottom: https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/issues/245
For a long running task (thread) I should be doing the following:

```
new Thread(() => {
// your exception here will stop the service or take down the app
}).Start();
```

Not this:

```
Task.Run(() => {
// your thrown exception here won't stop the service
});
```

Comment: Well if  you `await` the task (which you should be doing anyway) then you can wrap it in a `try-catch`

Comment: If this needs to run permanently, does that mean the loop needs to continue after an exception? If so, can it continue immediately, or does it need to wait for the main thread to have done something to handle the exception?

Comment: "runs permanently" makes me feel you have some kind of loop or waiting point in your main thread - otherwise the console program will exit. Can you please add a simple code example what you are doing?

Comment: Your question is too broad. As @MickyD notes, by observing the task (with e.g. `await` or attempting to retrieve the `Result` or checking the `State`, which will be set to `Faulted`, and `Exception` properties), you can see the exception in the main thread. But what's your main thread doing? Without a good [mcve] that clearly illustrates your scenario, there's no way to say what approach would work in your scenario.

Comment: My 2nd edit shows what I want to achieve, I can't wait for the task to finish, because it never does if there is no exception. My main thread works on processing events from the background thread. I'd like to be able to see the background task  exceptions on the main thread. Otherwise that task fails silently.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This makes the worker and main both threads that can be monitored, if one throws an exception, the app will quit out, or you can throw the exception

The worker thread has a monitor thread, it could handle the exception and do something sensible without quiting, or in this case it rethrows and sends it back to the Main thread which will quit the app.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = tokenSource.Token;

    var worker = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            var task = Task.Run(() => throw new Exception("hi"));
            await task;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Async...");
            throw;
        }

    }, token);

    var main = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }, token);

    var tasks = new[] { worker, main };
    var index = Task.WaitAny(tasks);

    var taskThatStopped = tasks[index];
    if (taskThatStopped.IsFaulted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task quit because of a fault");
        Console.WriteLine(taskThatStopped.Exception.InnerException.Message);
    }
    tokenSource.Cancel();
    try
    {
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, had to downvote this too. The OP thread runs in the background, while yours blocks the main due to the `Wait()` - so it's not really running in the background

Comment: John is correct (although  a little harsh). This solution will block the main thread from continuing.

Comment: @John I showed two variations to propagate exceptions at expected points, I wouldn't ever try and cause an uncontrolled exception on the main thread.  But you can do something like what I have here is a thread monitoring another thread.

Comment: @KeithNicholas I do want the main thread to fail if there is an unexpected exception on the background thread. Otherwise it fails silently and the app keeps running. If there's a bug I want it to fail asap.

Comment: Why not handle it gracefully?

Comment: the point of exceptions is they are within a thread.  They can cross thread boundaries on synchronization points.    If you want to quit out, make your current "Main" thread a worker thread and then monitor from main

Comment: @KeithNicholas I think your last point is my best bet, I'll need to have the main thread monitor exceptions in the tasks, then shutdown if any are detected.

Comment: @pogorman sorry didn't mean to sound harsh. There isn't really a clean way to do this without notifying the main thread through signals (waithandles) or some other mechanism.

Comment: @John no worries. In the the end I came to the conclusion that a Task wasn't what I should be using anyway. A Task is expected to eventually return. In my case I wanted a background thread for the lifetime of the app. A new Thread was more suitable in my case, plus if there's an exception it bubbles up to the main thread.